# Why does MariaDB CHAR_LENGTH return NULL instead of 0 when a field is NULL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to calculate to total size of stored metadata in a table using CHAR_LENGTH to add up the size of the relevant fields in each row to get a rough idea of the storage size of a result set.

I don't want the size of all the data in the table, only the size of a set of results.

However, some fields in the table have NULL values and as soon as CHAR_LENGTH hits one of those the whole calculation fails because CHAR_LENGTH returns NULL and not 0.

For example:

```
SELECT SUM(row_size) as `total` FROM ( SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(`field1`)+CHAR_LENGTH(`field2`)+CHAR_LENGTH(`field3`)+CHAR_LENGTH(`field4`) as `row_size` FROM `meta_data` WHERE `id` = 1 AND `id2` = 2 ) as tbl1;
```

For some queries this works and I get the size in bytes but for any that have a NULL value on any field in any row of the results I get nothing.

Why would CHAR_LENGTH not return 0 for a NULL value?

I suppose the next best thing is to get the results back and iterate through them in code to add up the size. I was hoping to avoid doing that but it might be the only way?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/char_length/ : "If the argument is NULL, it returns NULL.". So, it is not a bug, it is a feature ;-). I try to solve the problem with SUM or CONCAT, but no luck

Comment: SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(IFNULL(null, "")); works and return 0 !

Comment: SELECT SUM(row_size) as `total` FROM ( SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(IFNULL(`field1`, ''))+CHAR_LENGTH(IFNULL(`field2`, '')+CHAR_LENGTH(IFNULL(`field3`, ''))+CHAR_LENGTH(IFNULL(`field4`, '')) as `row_size` FROM `meta_data` WHERE `id` = 1 AND `id2` = 2 ) as tbl1;

Comment: is that realted to serverfault? no is it Stackfault yes?! :-)

Comment: No, this belongs on [dba.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround each with `COALESCE(..., 0)`.

```
mysql> SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(null), CHAR_LENGTH(''), CHAR_LENGTH('abc');
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| CHAR_LENGTH(null) | CHAR_LENGTH('') | CHAR_LENGTH('abc') |
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|              NULL |               0 |                  3 |
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+

mysql> SELECT COALESCE(CHAR_LENGTH(null), 0);
+--------------------------------+
| COALESCE(CHAR_LENGTH(null), 0) |
+--------------------------------+
|                              0 |
+--------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT LENGTH('') AS len, CHAR_LENGTH('') AS char_len;
+-----+----------+
| len | char_len |
+-----+----------+
|  16 |        4 |
+-----+----------+
```

Be aware that there is overhead in any string -- maybe a comma between them, maybe a newline, maybe something else.

Also, `CHAR_LENGTH()` gives a *character* count, not a *byte* count.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would CHAR_LENGTH not return 0 for a NULL value?

Because *any* function (except the likes of NVL(), obviously) will return NULL if passed a NULL argument.  Formally:

```
f(NULL) == NULL
```

More importantly:

```
NULL != ''
```

An empty string is .. well ..  an empty string.
A NULL marks the *absence* of data.

Not the same thing.
(Unless, of course, you're trying to use varchar data in an Oracle Database, which *still* can't tell the difference, *even* in the 2020's).